# Configuring eclipse to consider .sah extension as .js extension

Tags: javascript, eclipse, sahi

I have imported a framework in eclipse. It contains files with .sah extension. 
I want eclipse to consider those .sah files as .js files (javascript files), so that editing and working on that frameworks get easier. So that I can use short cuts like F3(like pressing F3 takes us to function defnition in java project) and all..

Thanks..

Comment: Right-click a `.sah` file and choose _Open With > Others..._, select the JavaScript editor, check _Use it for all '.sah' files_ and click _OK_.

Comment: @howlger I did that, To test it I created two .sah files, In one I created methods and in other I called those methods. Now I opened those two files as u suggested. I went to one file where I have called methods and selected method and pressed F3, it did not move me to function defnition. I tried with cntrl+click then also it does not took me to methos defnition. But when I changed those two files extension to .js extension and irrespective of opening them with the way u described above. When i press F3 it takes me to function defnition.

Answer (score 3):

To treat `.sah` files as `.js` files, do the following:

1. In ***Window > Preferences: General > Content Types*** select the content type ***Text > JavaScript Source File***
2. In the section ***File associations*** click ***Add...*** and enter `*.sah`

Make sure, the project is a JavaScript project and the `.sah` files are in the Include Path (*Project > Properties: JavaScript > Include Path*, tab *Source*).

Comment: howlger  With the solutions you have suggested , it is just going to highlight variables , keywords etc.  My problem is : If a function with name "gettest()" is called in one .sah file , If I select "gettest()" and press F3 then it should take me directly to the .sah file where I have defined function "gettest()".

Comment: Navigation between two `.sah` files works for me, if the content type was registered as described (_Open With..._ for all `.sah` files is not sufficient) and both files are in the include path (which is only possible if `.sah` is registered as content type and not as file association).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment on [howlger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50525785/8816775), so to expand on that answer:

If your file is not found as a **Child** of **Text** in **Window > Preferences: General > Content Types**, then you may need use **Add Child** to add your filetype (e.g., SAH) as a **Child** of **Text**. Then add the file association in **File associations** (e.g., *.sah), within the same window. Then add your preferred editor in **Associated editors** (e.g., Text Editor), also in the same window.