# How to change default comparison mode from binary to text in Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, compare

How to change default comparison mode from binary to text in Eclipse IDE? Currently it's set to binary and I could not find an option to change that from `Preferences > General > Compare/Patch`.

I am trying to compare flat text files.

[image]

Comment: If _Default_ is selected, the file content is used to decide whether to compare it as binary or as text. Make sure the correct encoding is set. Which kind of files do you compare?

Comment: I am comparing CSV files, created using the [Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/archives/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVFormat.html#EXCEL) library

Comment: Make sure the correct text encoding is set: right-click and choose _Properties_ (or Alt+Enter), in _Resource_ you can change the _Text file encoding_ (this can also be changed on folder, on project and on workspace level). If this does not help, try to add `*.csv` as content type of _Text_: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50525785/6505250

Comment: We have *.epf files (eclipse preference files from workspace mechanics) and the hint from @howlger made the difference. I added a new content type via preferences and then text compare was used as default.

Comment: I am having a similar problem with **PHP Development Tools 6.2** in Eclipse build **20190314-1200**. Comparing *.php* files defaults to "*PHP Content Type Compare*". But it doesn't work well & I want it to default to "*PHP Compare*" or "*Text Compare*".